# How to slide collection of views in circular way

Tags: android

I have four surface views and I want to show one at a time. If I want to see the next, I need to slide from right to left for next surface view. Its like film strip. What android component can be used to achieve this?  Any direction will be grateful.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the `InfiniteViewPager` could help you : https://github.com/antonyt/InfiniteViewPager

In your layout, you can use :

```
<com.antonyt.infiniteviewpager.InfiniteViewPager 
       android:id="@+id/pager" 
       android:layout_width="match_parent" 
       android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

In your Activity , wrap your PageAdapter in the `InfinitePagerAdapter` :

```
PagerAdapter adapter = new InfinitePagerAdapter( ... a PageAdapter ... );
```

Comment: Thanks for the git. I am going try this one.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `TabSwipe` functionality.

which ll help you to do slide from one view to other view **Right to left** and **Left to right**.

Read:

1. [Tabs and swipe views](http://www.lucazanini.eu/2012/android/tabs-and-swipe-views/?lang=en)
2. [Horizontal view swiping with viewpager](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html)

Comment: Thanks. Another guy also mentioned about the same component.